# Why am I getting a null value in localStorage even after parsing it?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to build a crypto tracker where you can add the items by clicking a button. Each time the button is clicked, the array should be added to the storage with the name "crypto" and then on another component where it is the portfolio one we should be able to get the items.

Here is where I set the item to an array whenever I click the add button:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './tracker.css'
import Navigation from './Nav.js'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function Tracker() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [portfolio, setPortfolio] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false' , {
            'mode': 'no-cors',
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            }
        })
        setData(result.data)
      }
      fetchData()
    }, 1000)
  }, [])


    return (
        <div>
        <Navigation />
          <div className="tracker__names">
            <b>Coins</b>
            <b>Symbol</b>
            <b>Price</b>
            <b>Market Cap</b>
          </div>
            {data.map((coins, i) => {
              const addToPortfolio = () => {
                setPortfolio([...portfolio, data[i]])

                localStorage.setItem('crpyto', JSON.stringify(portfolio))
              }


                return (
                  <>
                  <div className="tracker__main">
                    <div className="tracker__img">
                        <img src={coins.image} className="tracker__image"/>
                      <button key={i} onClick={addToPortfolio}>{coins.id}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tracker__symbol">
                        <p>{coins.symbol}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tracker__price">
                    <p></p>
                        ${coins.current_price}
                    </div>
                    <div className="tracker__market">
                    <p></p>
                        ${coins.market_cap}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tracker
```

Here is the component where I want to get the item:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Navigation from './Nav.js'

function Portfolio() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('crypto')) || '')

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(value)
}, )

    return (
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          {value}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Portfolio
```

Comment: Could it be the typo when setting the item `localStorage.setItem('crpyto'...` ?

Comment: no, the item is set correctly

Comment: here you set `localStorage.setItem('crpyto', JSON.stringify(portfolio))` and get it `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('crypto'))`  set  `crpyto` instead of  `crypto`

Answer (score 1):

It is because `useState` is executed before `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('crypto'))` and once you get the value from the localstorage, component doesn't re-render.

Instead do:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const crypto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('crypto'))
  if(crypto) setValue(crypto)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In React you can't set a state var and on the next line save it in localStorage (or even read it). This because `setPortfolio` is async!

To solve this you have I think 2 ways:

1. store value and not state variable:

   ```
   localStorage.setItem('crpyto', JSON.stringify([...portfolio, data[i]]))
   ```
2. use an `useEffect` hook:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('crpyto', JSON.stringify(portfolio))
   }, [portfolio])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when yo uare setting state like this, in the next block of code, `portfolio` won't necessarily have the updated state.

```
setPortfolio([...portfolio, data[i]])

localStorage.setItem('crpyto', JSON.stringify(portfolio))
```

update the portfolio like this.

```
const newPortfolio = [...portfolio, data[i]];

setPortfolio(newPortfolio )

localStorage.setItem('crpyto', JSON.stringify(newPortfolio))
```